# Firebase Error: Failed to fetch Run service undefined

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to deploy the firebase functions and getting the error:

> Error: Failed to fetch Run service undefined`

I've already tried to update firebase-tools, but it did not help. Could you please help to resolve it?

Comment: What finally worked for me, is to run `firebase deploy`. It will deploy everything that you have (hosting, rules, functions). 

Not the best way, however, for some reason it allows to deploy the functions

Answer (score 32):

I had same error in windows 10.
`firebase deploy --only functions`

v11.18.0 has fixed the error.

```bash
npm install -g firebase-tools --force

npm audit fix
```

Comment: Still same error.

Comment: @Hiti3 Remember to run `firebase --version` to make sure it's actually updated.

Comment: For me, i had to restart the terminal after updating my npm dependencies

Comment: In my case I was on a older node version, had to first switch to 16.* then update firebase-tools

Answer (score 13):

Make sure that firebase-tools is actually updated. Try `firebase --version` and see if it is `v11.18.0`.

I had firebase installed with `pnpm` globally, so `npm update` did not actually update the correct package.

Comment: To force the update to 11.18.0 run:

`npm install -g firebase-tools@11.18.0 --force`

then restart the terminal (I failed to do this and firebase --version wasn't updating for me)

Answer (score 7):

As others have pointed out, this is an issue with an older version.

**Manual workaround:** before deployment, go to Firebase admin console, and delete all existing cloud functions there. If the console is clean, the deploy command will work.

**Proper solution:** Upgrade firebase cli version.

On macOS, I noticed no matter how many times I run `npm install` it never actually updated.

This command finally updated it for me:

`curl -sL https://firebase.tools | upgrade=true bash`

Verify it using `firebase --version`, mine is at `11.22.0` now.

Comment: You're the man! Totally saved me hours, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After a day of try and error. I noticed that no matter what I do the `firebase --version` never updates. `v11.0.1` or whatever it is in your case.
I tried a simple workaround on this problem as following:

1. Downloaded the firebase [standalone binary](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#windows) from their official webpage
2. [optional] copied it to C:\firebase (For easy access next time)
3. Run it from there, it will open up a terminal, you can now `cd E:\some\file\location\to\cloud_functions` then you can do `firebase init` and `firebase deploy`
   Furthermore, while you're having the terminal opened, you can check `firebase --version` to see that this terminal does have the latest version of the firebase-tools unlike the global windows cmd. At least this solved the problem for me, I wanted to share it in case it might help someone!

Answer (score 1):

also check node version. I had node 16 selected and it was *too new* for firebase-functions 3.20.0 and npm 8.19.3.
Selecting with `nvm use 14` did the trick here.

Comment: Yep selecting node v14 did the trick for me also
Thanks @arno-teigseth

Answer (score 0):

Another quick workaround will be to deploy the function through the [google cloud console](https://console.cloud.google.com/functions) directly.

Answer (score 0):

Installing the latest version of the firebase-functions package and changing node from 10 to 14 in functions/package.json did it for me. Deleting package.json might also be wise.

Comment: @jermey I don't think deleting `package.json` would help.

Comment: Haha. I think @rabra might be right. :D